# Custom Spring AOP Annotation Not Working for Default Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to add already working AOP annotation around a new method in the class where it is already placed. Its not working for the new method which I have defined as a default method to an interface (not working even when not overriden) and I'm unable to find the cause of the same. Code is

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PaymentPlanLocking {}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class PaymentPlanLockAspect
{
..
@Around("@annotation(PaymentPlanLocking)")
    public Object paymentPlanLocking(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
..
```

```java
public interface PaymentOrchestratorService<RQ, RS>
{

    /**
     * @param request to validate
     */
    void validate(RQ request) throws PaymentServiceException;

    /**
     * @param request to execute
     * @return response
     */
    RS execute(RQ request) throws PaymentServiceException;

    /**
     * @param request to execute
     * @return response
     */
    default RS doExecute(RQ request) throws PaymentServiceException{
        throw new RuntimeException("please override this method in subclass if using old model with execute-wrapped");
    }

}
```

```java
@Service("holdPaymentService")
public class HoldPaymentOrchestrationService extends AbstractService<HoldResponse, HoldRequest>
        implements PaymentOrchestratorService<HoldRequest, HoldResponse>
{
...

@PaymentPlanLocking
    @Override
    public HoldResponse execute(HoldRequest holdRequest) throws PaymentServiceException

@PaymentPlanLocking
    @Override
    public HoldResponse doExecute(HoldRequest holdRequest) throws PaymentServiceException
```

Interception working for **execute(HoldRequest holdRequest)** but not for **doExecute(HoldRequest holdRequest)**. Please help me with the fix for this.

Comment: How is doExecute() triggered?. Please share that piece of code. Also note that self invocation of methods will not be intercepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works flawlessly for me. The only explanation why `doExecute(..)` interception is not working for you is that you use self-invocation, e.g. like this:

```java
  @PaymentPlanLocking
  @Override
  public HoldResponse execute(HoldRequest holdRequest) throws PaymentServiceException {
    return doExecute(holdRequest);
  }

  @PaymentPlanLocking
  @Override
  public HoldResponse doExecute(HoldRequest holdRequest) throws PaymentServiceException {
    return new HoldResponse();
  }
```

It is a classical Spring AOP beginner's mistake to assume that this is working, even though it is clearly [documented otherwise](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) (search for the term "self-invocation").

So the problem was not in the code you showed in your question, but it is in the code you chose to hide from us. Please be advised to learn why an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in every question is so important and ask better next time. Thank you.